# How to generate barcode in CodeIgniter-3.0rc2 using zend barcode library

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, barcode

Here is my controller and view. image is not return by controller.before this I used codeignter version 2.2 . there work properly but in the CodeIgniter-3.0rc2 is not working.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('index.php/barcode');?>"  alt="not show" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:90%;"/>
```

below is my controller:

```
<?php
class barcode extends MY_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        //I'm just using rand() function for data example
        $this->load->library('zend');
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');

        $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
        $rendererOptions = array('imageType'          =>'png', 
                                 'horizontalPosition' => 'center', 
                                 'verticalPosition'   => 'middle');
        $imageResource= Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
        return $imageResource;   
    }
}
?>
```

output is not show

Answer (score 1):

Using `return` is incorrect. You should be able to just do:

```
Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
```

And this should display the image on screen.

Comment: I use this .. it is not working in codigniter version 3.0 but work in 2.1 and 2.0 version properly. I don't know what to do..

Comment: I get `Non-existent class: Barcode` in version 2.x. Should I change the file name to `Zend_Barcode.php` instead of `Barcode.php`?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for using my library..

Check this issue :
https://github.com/desta88/Codeigniter-Barcode-Generator-Zend-Library/issues/1 (The EXT constant has been removed on CI 3)

Just change  constant, from EXT  to '.php', in your libraries/Zend.php

Or

Download here, I've been updated from this issue :
http://api.mdesain.com/Codeigniter-Barcode-Generator-Zend-Library/barcode.zip